# How do I import existing SSH keys into Seahorse?

Tags: ssh, seahorse

Is there a way to import existing SSH keys to Seahorse?

Comment: Bug Confirmed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/372608

Answer (score 3):

**Export and Import Keys**

Seahorse can import SSH keys from the clipboard or a key file.
Seahorse allows users to specify a SSH key file. Seahorse does not change
the content of imported files, instead, Seahorse copies the imported files
to ~/.ssh with non-duplicated file names.

Seahorse can export public key or private key info to new files.
Seahorse can copy public key info to the clipboard.

> open seahorse -> file - import.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 10.10. It's as if Seahorse ignores the SSH keys.

Comment: Error while importing private and public keys: "file:///home/manager/Desktop/id_rsa: Invalid file format". Any thoughts?..

Comment: it seems a bug in seahorse but you can copy your private key to `.ssh/id_rsa` and your public key to `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, and it appeared in seahorse.

Comment: Same problem: "Invalid file format". Even tried copying the key and doing Edit->Paste Keys, as described in the Seahorse help. No luck.

Comment: I ran into the "Invalid file format" error, too. However, creating an id_rsa.pub file in the same folder fixed it. You can do this with `ssh-keygen -y`.

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs importing keys in "seahorse".  Don't seem to be fixed in any release yet, but the bug gives workarounds.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/372608

Answer (score -1):

if you have already generated the ssh key on the machine, then you should ssh to that machine, then execute this:

```
 ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@host
```

user= your username of the system that you want to import

host= your pc hostname, the pc that you want to import key to.

What this happens is, that command calls the machine to send to your pc that you are trying to import the key.